# How can I implement Unobserved components model in R?

Tags: r

I need to check if the day of the week or month of the year has effect on stock returns. I decided to use unobserved components model with "rucm" package in R because it can extract seasonal characteristics from time series. In my case, I want to determine if there exists daily and monthly seasonality. My dataset is just a time series of daily stock returns:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1388966400, 1389139200, 1389225600, 
1389312000, 1389571200, 1389657600, 1389744000, 1389830400, 1389916800, 
1390176000, 1390262400, 1390348800, 1390435200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), LogReturn = c(-0.009, 0.016, 0.021, 
0.036, 0.049, 0.092, 0.023, -0.05, 0.044, -0.018, 0.001, -0.021, 
-0.022)), .Names = c("Date", "LogReturn"), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image] This is what it looks like

The code I used:

```
install.packages(rucm)
library(rucm)
model1<-ucm(formula=LogReturn~0,data=data, level=TRUE,slope=FALSE,season=TRUE,season.length=30)
```

I put season.length =30 randomly. I thought that if I have daily data and seasonality is daily, season.length should be 1, but it doesnt accept 1.

And my output looks like this

Estimated variance:
"Irregular_Variance"      "Level_Variance"    "Season_Variance"

As you can see I didnt get much information on how day of the week or month of the year affects stock returns. Could you please help me with this problem?

Update1. I added some features to my dataset. Now it shows what day of the week is on each date and added proxy variables for each day of the week.

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1388966400, 1389139200, 1389225600, 
1389312000, 1389571200, 1389657600, 1389744000, 1389830400, 1389916800, 
1390176000, 1390262400, 1390348800, 1390435200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), LogReturn = c(-0.009, 0.016, 0.021, 
0.036, 0.049, 0.092, 0.023, -0.05, 0.044, -0.018, 0.001, -0.021, 
-0.022), Dayoftheweek = c("Monday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"), proxymonday = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), proxytuesday = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), proxywednesday = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), proxythursday = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), proxyfriday = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Date", "LogReturn", "Dayoftheweek", 
"proxymonday", "proxytuesday", "proxywednesday", "proxythursday", 
"proxyfriday"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It looks like this[image]

Comment: Have you plotted the data (I'd suggest a pair of barplots plotting returns on the y and day or month on the x) to explore the data first?

Comment: @griffinevo yes I plotted the data, but I have lots of observations and you cant really see anything. Even if I could, I want to make formal test.

Comment: It's not relevant to your issue, but why not just use a chi square test?

Comment: @griffinevo I know that there are different ways to test what I am looking for, but I need to use unobserved components model in my paper

Comment: Ok. It would be helpful to provide dummy data, code and output so we can replicate your issue easily

Comment: @griffinevo, I will add dummy data, but it may take some time for me because I am not experienced at using this site. But if you are interested, my data is just a matrix with 2 columns. first is date, and second is stock returns

Comment: Something like this: `date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-31"), "days");
returns <- sample(c(0:20), replace = T, size = length(date));
df <- data.frame(date, returns)`

Comment: @griffinevo, I added dummy data, I am not sure if I did this the right way

Comment: I'm unable to understand why you think that a seasonal component could be estimated for a span of dates less than 20 days duration.

Comment: @42- I have dates for 10 years. Here I provided reproducible example. I am new to this site, so I wasnt sure what to do. I think that pasting here 3000 variables would be wrong

Comment: An example is only reproducible if it can be transferred to another computer and have code run against it. The way to make a large example is to construct it in code and show that code.

Comment: @42- You are right of course, but for my specific example does it matter that I have shown example with 20 dates? I am only interested in R code. I think that for R it doesnt matter how large or small my sample is

Comment: I tried using that micro-example and could not make any sense of the results. A different way to approach this would be to construct a dataset that has the features you seek, and then run the modeling function to understand what sort of encoding or summarization it can deliver. Many package authors will include such examples in their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not mentioning using RUCM because I am not familiar enough with the unobserved components model. But it seems the question you posed can be answered in another manner.

It seems to me there are two separate questions you are interested in. The first is the day of the week as the independent variable and the second is the month of the year as the independent component. Contingently, you also may want to look at the interaction of day of the week * month of the year. So let's break this up:

First let's look at the day of the week. You want to first find the mean dollars for each day. Your null hypothesis in this case would be that there are no day-to-day differences versus the alternative hypothesis which is at least one day will have a significant difference from the other days. To see this, we use `anova` as a function of `dayofweek`: (in this example, `dat` is the name of your dataset)

```
datsum <- anova(lm(LogReturn~dayofweek))
```

This yields:

```
> datsum
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: LogReturn
          Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
dayofweek  4 0.0066421 0.0016605   1.266 0.3587
Residuals  8 0.0104932 0.0013116
```

Based on your data that you provided it seems there is no significant day effect. But like you said this is only a small portion of the data.

Now, you can do this based on month, although since months don't have a uniform number of days, you are going to have to adjust for it. But you can do the same thing again by `anova(lm(LogReturn ~ Month, data = dat))`.

Now using ARIMA modeling, you can find seasonality. Here is a tutorial of [time series](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/12/complete-tutorial-time-series-modeling/).

Another option is to use [double-seasonal time series](https://petolau.github.io/Forecast-double-seasonal-time-series-with-multiple-linear-regression-in-R/).

Since you have not provided more data, it is hard for me to demonstrate it here. But both of the linked guides will help you structure your code and your data to perform seasonal analysis. I provided the `anova` as a starting guide and a launch point for you thinking about this.